# Implementing interface with many methods = huge class. Patterns come to rescue?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I have an interface with a lot of methods. (which i cannot split into different interfaces)

When i create a class that implements the interface i get a lot of methods in 1 class file.

Things get worst when the body of all these methods get larger -> the class file becomes huge and quite difficult to navigate.

Even with ide's like eclipse because the Outline window containing all classes get a vertical scrollbar because not all methods can fit in the outline.

Is there a pattern that prevents this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite understand why you cannot split the interface into multiple ones...

I surely would try to use inheritance, like:

First interface:

```
public interface FatherInterface {
    String methodOne(String var);

    String methodTwo(String var);

    String methodThree(String var);
}
```

Second interface:

```
public interface SonInterface extends FatherInterface {
    String methodFour(String var);

    String methodFive(String var);
}
```

Third interface:

```
public interface SecondSonInterface extends SonInterface {
    String methodSix(String var);

    String methodSeven(String var);
}
```

And so on... Each interface inheriting from the preceding one.

As for class files becoming large, go with inheritance too.

Father class:

```
public class Father implements FatherInterface
```

Son class:

```
public class Son extends Father implements SonInterface
```

And so on...

---

### Edit

If you cannot split the interface (as when given by third party), I would do the implementations of the methods by parts. That is, only some of them implemented in each class. Using abstract classes if needed (or leaving blank methods). Each class inheriting from the above and implementing some of the remaining methods.

Comment: what if interface is given by third party for which OP has no control over?

Comment: Did not think about that. I've made an edit adressing that: implement methods by steps, leave blank methods.

Comment: @PedroH.N.Vieira cheers, i like the idea in your edit, using abstract methods in class that extend's interface and writing method body for these abstract methods in another class. That seems to split up my big class in small chunks.

Comment: This answer assumes there's a hierarchical relation (sub types) between the sets of methods in each of those interfaces.

Comment: @GeorgeAristy exactly! What if most of the methods or groups of methods in the interface are on the same conceptual level? It does not seem that Java provides a nice way of using composition in this case. Best thing I can think of is immediately delegating all method calls to their own services and put the business logic there. That leaves the interface implementation as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to split the implementation in many classes.
But you can delegate from the implementing class to any other classes.
This will reduce the code in the implementation but the number of methods stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this reply after an answer is accepted, hoping that future comers might find it useful.

---

As [simas_ch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simas-ch) said:

> No there is no way to split the implementation in many classes. But
>   you can delegate from the implementing class to any other classes.
>   This will reduce the code in the implementation but the number of
>   methods stay the same.

---

Once I worked on a rather huge application in which I had to define a `Lifecycle` interface, which contained many states and many functions that could create a hassle, so I came around with something like this:

You can create a class and make it abstract and implement most of the common functions.

```
public interface TheBigFunctional {
    public void functionalA();
    public void functionalB();
    public void functionalC();
    //....
    public void functionalZ();
}

public abstract class FunctionalBase implements TheBigFunctional {
    public void functionalA() {
        aInternal();
    }

    protected abstract void aInternal();

    // Rest of methods implementations.
    // You may choose to skip those if you want child classes to implement them.
}


public class FunctionalTypeFoo extends FunctionalBase {
    // Implementations.
}

public class FunctionalTypeBar extends FunctionalBase {
    // Implementations.
}
```

---

There are many (good) ways to come around the sitation, but I am sharing what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could employ the strategy pattern on the big interface by implementing some of those methods from different classes. Then, when you wish to use any of those methods, simply call it from the class that implements your 'large' interface.

More on strategy pattern here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would consider whether all methods in your class are well designed. Probably they do not have clear purpose and should be splitted per few. 
You have to define clear purpose of some particular interface.

Besides, if you are using Java 8, consider ability to provide some default implementation for some methods.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a pattern that prevents this from happening?

In Java:

- [Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping): If you can group sets of methods into different interfaces such that a clear hierarchical relation makes sense. This is what the accepted answer is assuming.
- [Interface Segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle): If you can group sets of methods into different sibling "domains" or "categories". Take a look at [this](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github/blob/6747249f898318148bc1a46596a95945a7789749/src/main/java/com/jcabi/github/Github.java#L90) example from [jcabi-github](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github). See how `Github` is this API's entrypoint, while exposing different sets of functionalities via successive "grouping" interfaces.